# Film About a city surrounded by a wall, healthy people on the inside and infected on the outside

Tags: story-identification, movie

It’s about a city rounded by a wall, inside the wall only for healthy people and outside the wall for infected people. One time the gate is open and people from outside trying to get to the city and the government who see this give an order to close the gate. When people were pressed together there was a man whose hand was wedged against the gate, there was a woman who saw the incident, she felt sorry, so this woman was looking for medicine to be given to people outside the gate. One of the parts that I remember was that this woman came into a place and then she took her eyes off and directed them into the room and this woman can see through her eyes that are separated.

Comment: She ***TOOK HER EYES OFF***!? What the what?

Comment: You're not thinking of The Masque of The Red Death, are you?

https://www.google.com/search?q=the+masque+of+the+red+death+1964+youtube&rlz=1C5CHFA_enGB779GB779&oq=The+Masque+of+The+Red+Death%2C+are+you%3F&aqs=chrome.3.69i57j0l7.10736j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this might be the 2008 film *[Doomsday](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doomsday_(2008_film))*

> In 2008, an unknown killer virus, known as the "Reaper Virus", has infected the country of Scotland. Unable to contain the outbreak or cure the infected, the British government builds a massive 30-foot wall that isolated Scotland from the rest of Great Britain. Whilst the quarantine was deemed a success, the extreme method employed by the government destroys diplomatic and economic relations between the UK and the rest of the world. Now a pariah state, the UK collapses into a dystopia, rife with unemployment, civil unrest and extreme economic turmoil.
>
> 27 years after the start of the quarantine, a group of armed police officers discover several people in London infected with Reaper Virus during a routine investigation. Prime Minister John Hatcher shares satellite footage of survivors in Scotland with domestic security chief Captain Nelson. Believing a cure may exist, Hatcher orders Nelson to send a team into Scotland to find medical researcher Dr. Kane, who was working on a cure when Scotland was quarantined. Nelson chooses his top police officer, Major Eden Sinclair, to lead the team. Sinclair is originally from Scotland, having escaped as the quarantine began at the cost of her right eye. For Sinclair the mission is also personal, as she hopes to learn if her mother survived or not.
>
> Sinclair's team crosses the wall to Glasgow, Dr. Kane's last known location. In Glasgow, while searching the local hospital for survivors, Sinclair and her team are ambushed by a group of marauders. Sgt. Norton and Dr. Stirling manage to escape, while the team suffers heavy casualties. Sinclair and Dr. Talbot are captured by what turns out to be a huge gang of brutal cannibals, led by the power-hungry Sol, who plans to use her as leverage to cross the wall, allowing his army to start their invasion on England, which will bring Great Britain into the Golden Age. He then leaves for the sacrificial ceremony to join the rest of his gang, who burn Dr. Talbot alive before devouring his body. With the help of Cally, another prisoner, Sinclair escapes and kills Viper, Sol's second-in-command. After meeting with Norton and Stirling, they escape on a train. Cally reveals that she and Sol are Kane's children. Unsatisfied with Kane's rule, Sol abolishes martial law by creating his own army....

As noted in the summary, Major Sinclair has a bionic eye that she can remove and view footage through.

### Trailer